# Connecting survey vessel points with lines on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing

I am collecting vessels historical points on ArcGIS Online, these are received as csv from the web, based on an API call., but I would like to be able to connect the dots, anytime I retrieve these points automatically.

I there any way I can do this, or via a geoprocessing toolbox that knows when a new csv is added to the web map?

[image]

Comment: What attribute information do you have - hopefully a timestamp and id that links to the same vessel?

Comment: @Mapperz yes, those are included in the attribute, as well as its heading and course